# Iterate over multiple arrays into php query

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, foreach

### Overall Project:

Save multiple arrays from AJAX

### Iterating through the array in PHP:

I've managed to successfully save 2 arrays by using `array_combine` and foreach (see example), but now

### Problem:

I have 20+ arrays of dynamic content that I need to iterate into my query statement.

Successful AJAX Sample

```
var setTitle = new Array();
    $('form input[name="setTitle[]"]').each(function () {
        setTitle.push($(this).val());
    });
    var setUnitId = new Array();
    $('form input[name="setUnitId[]"]').each(function () {
        setUnitId.push($(this).val());
    });

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form_process2_wkout.php',
        data: {
            setTitle:setTitle,
            setUnitId:setUnitId,
            // ...and so on...//
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false
```

PHP (form_process2_wkout.php) is receiving each $_POST...
I've combined them into an array...

```
    $setArray = array(
            $x_set_title,
            $x_set_unit_id,
            // ...and so on... //
    );
```

I've var_dump'ed this array to test...

```
$data= var_dump($setArray);
echo $data;
```

It produces the following:

```
array(24) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Ab Roller"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "Slide Back Lunge"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "Jump Squat"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "879"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "872"
    }
    ...and so on...
}
```

Not quite sure how write to `foreach` to iterate through these items:

```
foreach($setArray as $id => $key) {
    $set_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['setTitle']);
    $set_unit_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['setUnitId']);
    //...and so on.../

}
```

So that I can use them in the following query:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO ".$table1." (`goal_unit_id`,`goal_title`,...and so on...)
       VALUES ";
$sql.="('".$set_unit_id."','".$set_title."',...and so on...)";
```

I've referenced a number of other approaches, but no luck:

[PHP: Iterate over multiple arrays and build SQL INSERT query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23610571/3255695)

[array combine three or more arrays with php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6553752/3255695)

[Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4157810/3255695)

Comment: $setArray = array_merge($x_set_title,$x_set_unit_id,// ...and so on... //); try this

Answer (score 0):

Use global or class variable to achieve this like below, Please refer arra_map , array_merge api's in PHP

```
<?php

$x_set_title = array('Ab Roller', 'Slide Back Lunge', 'Jump Squat');
$x_set_unit_id = array('2', '879', '872');

function escape_str($title, $id)
{
   $dbc = $GLOBALS['dbc'];
   $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $title);    
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $id);  
   return (array($title, $id));
}

$setArray = array_map('escape_str', $x_set_title,$x_set_unit_id);

print_r($setArray);

foreach($setArray as $oneArray)
{
    echo $oneArray[0].'  '.$oneArray[1];
}
```

Comment: function was right. There may be an error in passing the parameters http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php check this example and fix the parameter errors

Comment: @stackoverflow.com/users/1662383/sundar Read through the php.net manual you provided. Still a bit greek to me. I simplified test of your function...

Comment: check this answer. If you wan to pass multiple parameters then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: I've been trying to get my head around where you're 2nd argument ($id) is meant to be generated from?

Comment: when ever the array map function calls the escape_str then $x_set_title array 0th element and $x_set_unit_id 0th element will be passed to the function. Please study further and see the examples in array_map API then you'll understand. Better please execute the Examples in the local machine and get clear idea about that